# Pandas - Build A Query String, Use To Slice DataFrame

Tags: string, pandas, parsing, dataframe

I have a bunch of data stored in a DataFrame.  I am trying to allows users to pass in query criteria in the form of:

```
column, operator, variable_name
```

So a user might pass in the following as an example

```
'Action equal allow,total_bytes > 10000,application neq facebook'
```

I parse that string by splitting and formatting into a query string that looks like this

```
query_string = (dframe['Action'] == 'allow') & (dframe['total_bytes'] > 10000) & ~(dframe[''Application] == 'facebook')
```

Then, I attempt to create a filtered table to return to the user by passing in the query_string I parsed the inputs to get.

```
dframe_filtered = dframe[query_string]
```

However this fails with a key error - I think because Python needs to see the query_string as not really a string - but Pandas series.  Is there a way to make this work?  Not sure you describe having Python not parse text as a string.  But hopefully you all take the meaning.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `df.query` and take the user input in that format?

Answer (score 1):

A crude, quick and dirty way to convert the query string (assuming it will always be in this format) into machine-readable form is:

```
from functools import reduce
s = 'Action equal allow,total_bytes > 10000,Application neq facebook'
symbols = {'equal':'==', '>': '>', 'neq':'!=',',':'&'}

s1 = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, symbols[y]), symbols, s)
splits=s1.split('&')
splits1 = '('+splits[0].replace(splits[0].split()[2], '\''+splits[0].split()[2]+'\'')+')&('
splits2 = splits[1]
splits3 = ')&('+splits[2].replace(splits[2].split()[2],'\''+splits[2].split()[2]+'\')')
s2 = splits1+splits2+splits3
df1.query(s2)

    Action  Application total_bytes
0   allow   app1    11000
3   allow   app3    15000
4   allow   app5    17000
```